How can I restrict uploads of different files when using a presigned URL for S3?
I am using the @aws-sdk/client-s3 library to create a presigned URL, and then I use this URL to upload a file to S3. While generating the presigned URL, I am using the Key attribute, which includes the file name and the content type.
However, the issue is that when I upload a file using the presigned URL, it allows me to upload any file. What I want to do is restrict file uploads if the file name and content type do not match the ones I used to generate the presigned URL.
Below is the code:
async getUploadPreSignedUrl(key, bucket, expiresInSeconds = 1800)
{
    try {
        const contentType = mime.lookup(key) || undefined;
        if (!contentType) {
            throw new Error('Invalid Content Type')
        }
        const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key, ContentType: contentType, }; 
        const putObjectCommand = new PutObjectCommand(params); 
        console.log(params, putObjectCommand)       
        const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(this.s3, putObjectCommand, 
        { expiresIn: expiresInSeconds, }); 
        return signedUrl;
    } 
catch (error) { 
 console.error("Error generating upload pre-signed URL:", error); throw error; }
}

What I want is that if we use a different file name or a different content type, the upload should return an error.

To ensure the signed url only works for uploading the file it was created with, you have to set conditions in your getUploadPreSignedUrl. There is a CreatePresignedPostCommand method from the @aws-sdk/client-s3 library that we need to create the actual command. I just rewrote your getUploadPreSignedUrl using that method and incorporating the checking conditions:


const { S3Client, CreatePresignedPostCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

    async getUploadPreSignedUrl(key, bucket, expiresInSeconds = 1800) {
        try {
            const contentType = mime.lookup(key) || undefined;
            if (!contentType) {
                throw new Error('Invalid Content Type');
            }

            // This is where you set the conditions, eq checks for equality
            const conditions = [
                { bucket: bucket },
                ['eq', '$key', key],
                ['eq', '$Content-Type', contentType]
            ];

            const params = {
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: key,
                Conditions: conditions,
                Expires: expiresInSeconds,
            };

            // Generate the presigned post URL using CreatePresignedPostCommand
            const command = new CreatePresignedPostCommand(params);
            const { url, fields } = await this.s3.send(command);

            return { url, fields };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error generating upload pre-signed URL:", error);
            throw error;
        }
  }



If any other file (different contentType or name) is uploaded with this signedUrl, it throws a 403 Forbidden error.
To use this upload method on the frontend, I added an example using the browser fetch API.


async function uploadFileToBucket(file, presignedUrlData) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Append fields from presignedUrlData.fields
    Object.entries(presignedUrlData.fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });

    // Append the file content here
    formData.append('file', file);

    // This uploads to the S3 bucket 
    try {
        const response = await fetch(presignedUrlData.url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Upload failed with status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        console.log("Your file uploaded successfully!");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
    }
}



I think this should solve your problem

Thanks for the reply! .Do we need to do this part of code mandatory? :"Append fields from presignedUrlData.fields" Because in case of my code am using Putcommand and dont have to use the fileds list to append formdata

Hi Soumya.
It is necessary to include the fields in the form data on the client side because those fields contain the necessary information for the S3 service to validate and process the upload request correctly.If you still want to use PutObjectCommand, you will have to do some server-side validation to check for the Content-Type and Key of the uploaded file. If they don't match the values, you can use the deleteObject from the s3 client sdk to delete the uploaded file. If you want me to edit the answer and help with a revised flow using PutObjectCommand, I can help with it.
